# JSF 2 browser is not caching resources

Tags: jsf, caching, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF component which is getting refreshed by a button via ajax request. This component has an image which changes in order to a value. If I look the network requests I can see that my browser is not caching the images but requesting them every single time I click. This causes some kind of "poping" in the view rendering.

I want to speed up the refresh time and the render time by caching the image. I've tried using a RequestFilter on GET method which sets the Cache-Control header to "public" but is not working.

Any idea?

### LatencyIndicator

```html
<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="#{cc.attrs.latencia ge cc.attrs.umbralAlto}">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:rojo.png']}"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="#{(cc.attrs.latencia lt cc.attrs.umbralAlto) and (cc.attrs.latencia ge cc.attrs.umbralMedio)}">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:ambar.png']}"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:verde.png']}"/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.latencia} ms."/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</composite:implementation>
```

### Sample.xhtml

```html
<h:body>
    <h:form id="miForm">
        <h:commandButton id="boton" value="Generar Latencia">
            <f:ajax render="@form" event="click" listener="#{latencyBean.actualizarLatencia()}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <miscomponentes:LatencyIndicator latencia="#{latencyBean.latencia}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could have various reasons:

- Did you set the project stage to `Development` via the context parameter  `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` in your `web.xml`? Because in this case JSF disables caching. Setting the parameter to `Production` (default value) should enable caching.
- Do you use a Mojarra version below 2.1.21? There was a bug in older versions that prevented caching. You might try a new version in this case.

Comment: Great. That worked. I just set the project stage to Production as you said and it worked for me.