# Primefaces-JSF distortion Issue

Tags: css, caching, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.3 & JSF 2.1.21, when ever I am navigating from one .xhtml to another .xhtml, I could see page is distorted for a sec for downloading CSS again and loading, please suggest how can I fix this issue.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017494/jsf-2-browser-is-not-caching-resources ?

Comment: Along with @JasperdeVries answer which is correct don't forget to also check out this PrimeFaces guide for performance optimization some web.xml settings: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/core/performance

Comment: I have implemented the changes suggested in above links, even upgraded the Mojarra version to use higher version-2.2.0 as recommended.
But, issue is still not fixed, observed the flickering/distortion in between navigations